# Design patterns to mitigate cache misses in runtime polymorphism in C++

Tags: c++, caching, polymorphism

I have a variety of derived class objects stored in a long array or vector. Each object in the vector is passed to a process that calls several of the object's member functions. There will probably be cache misses when consecutive objects in the vector have different derived types, but because VTables seem to be tied to member functions themselves, it would follow that there would be a cache miss for each new member function used by the process. Here is a simplified example of the behavior I am looking for:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


// Base Class
class Animal
{
  public:
    virtual void eat() = 0;
    virtual void sleep() = 0;
    virtual void roll_in_mud() = 0;    
};

// Derived class 1 
class Pig : public Animal
{
  public:  
    Pig(){}
    void eat() {std::cout << "The pig is eating" << std::endl;}
    void sleep() {std::cout << "The pig is sleeping" << std::endl;}
    void roll_in_mud() {std::cout << "The pig is rolling in the mud" << std::endl;}
};

// Derived class 2 
class Cow : public Animal
{
  public:  
    Cow(){}
    void eat() {std::cout << "The cow is eating" << std::endl;}
    void sleep() {std::cout << "The cow is sleeping" << std::endl;}
    void roll_in_mud() {std::cout << "The cow is rolling in the mud" << std::endl;}
};

// Process that operates on an Animal instance
void barnyard_activities(Animal& animal)
{
    animal.eat();
    animal.sleep();
    animal.roll_in_mud();
}



int main()
{
    // In reality this vector or array could hold millions of items
    std::vector<Animal*> animals;
    animals.push_back(new Pig);
    animals.push_back(new Cow);

    for (Animal* animal : animals) barnyard_activities(*animal);
    
    return 0;
}
```

The base class has only virtual methods so, hypothetically, the process `barnyard_activities` could know which derived class it is working with after just one virtual function call. Is there a design pattern that would allow the process to call the derived class methods directly or somehow eliminate the chance of cache misses after the first virtual function call?

My apologies if I have misunderstood how VTables work or if there is a similar discussion already on the forum that has somehow eluded me.

Comment: I wouldn't think the derived type has much to do with perceived cache misses. If you had a vector of 10000 cows, not every cow would be in your L1 cache. Right?  Your first order of business is to validate your assumption is true. Go measure performance and find the bottlenecks before trying to optimize for it. Often times, the perceived slowness of a program is the places you least expect it.  But if you're right, I'd love to be educated on this topic.

Comment: @StillUsesFORTRAN You are looking for visitor pattern via `variant`s. You might speed it up if processing order is unimportant (or is only important within concrete types) by simply creating a vector for each type; otherwise, vector of variant of possible types.

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't yet come across the `variant` structure. Order is not important, so when it comes time to optimize, I may just use vectors or arrays for each type inside a wrapper class then use static polymorphism for the process. Still, it would be nice (though not strictly necessary) to have the syntactic elegance of typical dynamic polymorphism.

Comment: Make `barnyard_activities` be a virtual method of the base class. This will cut down no virtual lookups.

Comment: For the very specific example that you gave, then store the words `pig`, `cow` etc.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor the methods in the example are stand-ins for methods that would require more computational effort. Though there may be a way that more implementation could occur in the base class. For some other reasons that are difficult to describe, it's not a great idea for me to make the process a member function.

Comment: I presume these aspects have been trimmed in order to make a minimal example:  virtual destructor, using raw pointers that are leaking instead of a smart pointer to manage object lifetime, two animals instead of a million animals, and not measuring the performance of an optimized build to validate that this concern is relevant.